# Ошибка при отправки запроса на вывод карты по адресу GMap.Net С# WindowsForms

Tags: c#, winforms, api, google-maps-api, gmap.net

Искользую вот этот гайд по поиску адреса на карте через ввод информации в textBox: http://csharpcoderr.com/2014/09/api-geocoding-google-and-gmap.html. Возникает следующая ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Весь мой код:

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Куплепродажа_и_аренда_недвижимости
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            comboBox1.DropDownStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
            comboBox2.DropDownStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;

            //Настройки для компонента GMap.
            gMapControl1.Bearing = 0;

            //CanDragMap - Если параметр установлен в True,
            //пользователь может перетаскивать карту
            ///с помощью правой кнопки мыши.
            gMapControl1.CanDragMap = true;

            //Указываем, что перетаскивание карты осуществляется
            //с использованием левой клавишей мыши.
            //По умолчанию - правая.
            gMapControl1.DragButton = MouseButtons.Left;

            gMapControl1.GrayScaleMode = true;

            //MarkersEnabled - Если параметр установлен в True,
            //любые маркеры, заданные вручную будет показаны.
            //Если нет, они не появятся.
            gMapControl1.MarkersEnabled = true;

            //Указываем значение максимального приближения.
            gMapControl1.MaxZoom = 18;

            //Указываем значение минимального приближения.
            gMapControl1.MinZoom = 2;

            //Устанавливаем центр приближения/удаления
            //курсор мыши.
            gMapControl1.MouseWheelZoomType =
            GMap.NET.MouseWheelZoomType.MousePositionAndCenter;

            //Отказываемся от негативного режима.
            gMapControl1.NegativeMode = false;

            //Разрешаем полигоны.
            gMapControl1.PolygonsEnabled = true;

            //Разрешаем маршруты
            gMapControl1.RoutesEnabled = true;

            //Скрываем внешнюю сетку карты
            //с заголовками.
            gMapControl1.ShowTileGridLines = false;

            //Указываем, что при загрузке карты будет использоваться
            //2х кратное приближение.
            gMapControl1.Zoom = 2;

            //Указываем что будем использовать карты Yandex.
            gMapControl1.MapProvider =
            GMap.NET.MapProviders.GMapProviders.GoogleMap;
            GMap.NET.GMaps.Instance.Mode =
            GMap.NET.AccessMode.ServerOnly;

            //Если вы используете интернет через прокси сервер,
            //указываем свои учетные данные.
            GMap.NET.MapProviders.GMapProvider.WebProxy =
            System.Net.WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy();
            GMap.NET.MapProviders.GMapProvider.WebProxy.Credentials =
            System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Запрос к API геокодирования Google.
            string url = string.Format(
            "https://www.google.ru/maps",
            Uri.EscapeDataString(textBox1.Text));

            //Выполняем запрос к универсальному коду ресурса (URI).
            System.Net.HttpWebRequest request =
            (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url);

            //Получаем ответ от интернет-ресурса.
            System.Net.WebResponse response =
            request.GetResponse();

            //Экземпляр класса System.IO.Stream
            //для чтения данных из интернет-ресурса.
            System.IO.Stream dataStream =
            response.GetResponseStream();

            //Инициализируем новый экземпляр класса
            //System.IO.StreamReader для указанного потока.
            System.IO.StreamReader sreader =
            new System.IO.StreamReader(dataStream);

            //Считывает поток от текущего положения до конца.
            string responsereader = sreader.ReadToEnd();

            //Закрываем поток ответа.
            response.Close();

            System.Xml.XmlDocument xmldoc =
            new System.Xml.XmlDocument();

            xmldoc.LoadXml(responsereader);

            if (xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("status")[0].ChildNodes[0].InnerText == "OK")
            {

                //Получение широты и долготы.
                System.Xml.XmlNodeList nodes =
                xmldoc.SelectNodes("//location");

                //Переменные широты и долготы.
                double latitude = 0.0;
                double longitude = 0.0;

                //Получаем широту и долготу.
                foreach (System.Xml.XmlNode node in nodes)
                {
                    latitude =
                    System.Xml.XmlConvert.ToDouble(node.SelectSingleNode("lat").InnerText.ToString());
                    longitude =
                    System.Xml.XmlConvert.ToDouble(node.SelectSingleNode("lng").InnerText.ToString());
                }

                //Варианты получения информации о найденном объекте.
                //Вариант 1.
                string formatted_address =
                xmldoc.SelectNodes("//formatted_address").Item(0).InnerText.ToString();

                //Вариант 2.
                //Массив, элементы которого содержат подстроки данного экземпляра, разделенные
                //одним или более знаками из separator.
                string[] words = formatted_address.Split(',');
                string dataMarker = string.Empty;
                foreach (string word in words)
                {
                    dataMarker += word + ";" + Environment.NewLine;
                }
                //Устанавливаем позицию карты.
                gMapControl1.Position = new GMap.NET.PointLatLng(latitude, longitude);

                //Указываем, что при загрузке карты будет использоваться
                //17ти кратное приближение.
                gMapControl1.Zoom = 17;

                //Обновляем карту.
                gMapControl1.Refresh();
            }
        }

        private void gMapControl1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Моя форма:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А посмотреть, что у вас в `responsereader` не судьба?

Comment: Чему вас учат простите в университете? Уровень университета, а не знаете базовых вещей по типу отладки. Когда падает ошибка, просто наведите на значение и посмотрите, валидный ли вам сервер дает ответ. Или же поставьте на проблемном мест (слева) точку остановки и запустите проект, также посмотрите что за ответ вы получаете, ну или на крайний случай выведите это значение в консоль, можете вовсе написать `Debugger.Break();`. Способов в общем много, смотрите, разбирайтесь.